# Declspec A Struct, when Creating a buffer to send into OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, c, struct, opencl

I tried searching for this through the forums, but couldnt find anything. I want to pass over a struct to my OpenCL file, but cant seem to make sense of the declspec_align function. Basically, Ive got two structs, and this is how ive tried to do this:

```
struct 2Floats {
  float x, y;
}

_declspec(align(8)) struct pos {
    _declspec(align(8)) 2Floats posi;
}
```

But this doesnt seem to be passing correctly, I was just wondering if someone could tell me how many bytes Id be passing? I assumed it would be 4 for a float, but it seems Im wrong.

Comment: Which api in OpenCL are you trying to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you probably want to do is align the data at the 16 bit byte boundary.  That should look like this:

```
_declspec(align(16)) struct pos {
    2Floats posi;
}
```

Note the number isn't the size of the data, but the alignment you need.  Under the covers, I'm sure OpenCL is trying to use some SIMD operation that requires memory alignment.  If you could provide the name of the function you are trying to call, I'm sure the documentation says something about the alignment necessary.  Most SIMD operations require alignment on the 16 bit boundary.

Again since the number is asking about the byte boundary and not the size of the data, it doesn't matter how large 2float is.  However, they are two 32 bit floats, so 8 bytes.